# Cant finde a way to download picture using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, base64

Most people use the url however the picture I try to download via selenium does not really have a url. In the html of the website it seems to be bas64 encoded.

```
<img id="captchaImage" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" width="250" height="50">
```

I already encoded it but when saved as jpg the file goes corrupt.

Encoded it does look like this:

```
b'u\xabZ\x8af\xa0{\xf8\xe9z\x06\xda\xb1\xee\xb8\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x02\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x08\x06\x06\x07\x06\x05\x08\x07\x07\x07\t\t\x08\n\x0c\x14\r\x0c\x0b\x0b\x0c\x19\x12\x13\x0f\x14\x1d\x1a\x1f\x1e\x1d\x1a\x1c\x1c $.\' ",#\x1c\x1c(7),01444\x1f\'9=82<.342\xff\xdb\x00C\x01\t\t\t\x0c\x0b\x0c\x18\r\r\x182!\x1c!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222\xff\xc0\x00\x11\x08\x002\x00\xfa\x03\x01"\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xff\xc4\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x01\x05\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\xff\xc4\x00\xb5\x10\x00\x02\x01\x03\x03\x02\x04\x03\x05\x05\x04\x04\x00\x00\x01}\x01\x02\x03\x00\x04\x11\x05\x12!1A\x06\x13Qa\x07"q\x142\x81\x91\xa1\x08#B\xb1\xc1\x15R\xd1\xf0$3br\x82\t\n\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a%&\'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xff\xc4\x00\x1f\x01\x00\x03\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\xff\xc4\x00\xb5\x11\x00\x02\x01\x02\x04\x04\x03\x04\x07\x05\x04\x04\x00\x01\x02w\x00\x01\x02\x03\x11\x04\x05!1\x06\x12AQ\x07aq\x13"2\x81\x08\x14B\x91\xa1\xb1\xc1\t#3R\xf0\x15br\xd1\n\x16$4\xe1%\xf1\x17\x18\x19\x1a&\'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xff\xda\x00\x0c\x03\x01\x00\x02\x11\x03\x11\x00?\x00\xf5\xe5U\xd8>Q\xd3\xd2\x9d\xb1\x7f\xba?*\x13\xee/\xd2\x9dLE\x1dY\xafa\xd1\xee\xe5\xd2\xeda\xb8\xbfX\x98\xc1\x14\xad\xb5Y\xf1\xc0\'\xfc\xfdGZ\xf1\xaf\x01\xfcZ\xbb\xb2\xd5\xe6\xd1<hJ3L\xc1n\xa5@\x8d\x03\x93\xca8\xec\xb9\xe8\x7f\x87\xe9\xd3\xdauW\xb9\x8fG\xbd{4g\xba[y\x0c*\xbdK\xed;@\xfcq_<]\xfc2\xf8\x89\xe2\xbb\x93\x7f\xaa\xc7\x07\xda\x02c\xcc\xb8tGp:\x03\xb4r{sHg\xd1\xab-\xb38@\xf1\x16 \x10\x01\x19 \xf450\x8d?\xb8\xbf\x95|^d\xd5|=\xad\x08fk\x8b[\xcb9p\xd1\xb3\x10P\x8e\xdfJ\xfb.\xcaO6\xc6\t\x04\xa9.\xf8\xd5\xbc\xc4 \x86\xc8\xea\x08\xea\r\x00K\xe5\xa7\xf7\x17\xf2\xa5\xf2\xd3\xfb\x8b\xf9V^\xab\xe2}\x0fC\x86Yu-V\xd2\xdcDp\xea\xd2\x02\xe0\xe38\xda9\'\x078\x035\xcaX|j\xf0U\xeeD\xb7\xd7\x16m\xbb\n.-\x9b\xe6\xf7\xca\xee\x18\xfa\xe2\x80=\x03\xcbO\xee/\xe5Uf\xd44\xbby|\xa9\xae\xed#\x93\xa6\xd7\x91A\xfc\x8d\\\xaf\x10\xb4\xf8\x1dy\xad]\\\xea\x9a\xf6\xac\xf6\xf7\x172\xbc\xbeL#qM\xc4\x9c\x12~\xbd\xa8\x03\xdbU"a\x95T#\xd4\x01N\xf2\xa3\xff\x00\x9ek\xf9W\xcdZ\xcax\xa3\xe0\xe6\xbb\x04V\xda\xa4\x97:|\xbf4a\xb3\xb1\xc6y\x05rpk\xdf<#\xe2(\xbcU\xe1\xbb]V%\xdb\xe6\x8c:\xff\x00u\x87Q@\x1b^T\x7f\xf3\xcd\x7f*_*?\xf9\xe6\x9f\x95;8\x195\x1cW0NH\x8ah\xe4+\xd4+\x03\x8a\x00\x7f\x93\x1f\xfc\xf3O\xfb\xe4P!\x8b\xfey\xa7\xfd\xf2)\xf4\xa2\x80\x19\xe4\xc5\xff\x00<\xd3\xfe\xf9\x14\xbeL_\xf3\xcd?\xef\x91O\x14\x8a\xea\xccB\xb0$u\x00\xf4\xa0\x04\xf2b\xff\x00\x9eI\xff\x00|\x8a_"/\xf9\xe4\x9f\xf7\xc8\xa7R\xd0\x03<\x88\xbf\xe7\x92\x7f\xdf"\x97\xc8\x87\xfey\'\xfd\xf2)\xf4\xb4\x00\xcf"\x1f\xf9\xe4\x9f\xf7\xc8\xa5\xf2!\xff\x00\x9eQ\xff\x00\xdf"\x9fK@\x0c\xfb<?\xf3\xc6?\xfb\xe4P-\xe1\xff\x00\x9e1\xff\x00\xdf"\xa4\xa5\x14\x01\x1f\xd9\xe1\xff\x00\x9e1\xff\x00\xdf"\x97\xec\xf0\x7f\xcf\x18\xff\x00\xef\x91R\n\x05\x003\xec\xf0\x7f\xcf\x18\xff\x00\xef\x91G\xd9\xa0\xff\x00\x9e1\xff\x00\xdf"\xa4\x14\xb4\x01\x1f\xd9\xa0\xff\x00\x9e1\xff\x00\xdf\x02\xb0\xae\x00[\x99@\x00\x00\xe4\x00>\xb5\xd1W=s\xff\x00\x1fS\x7f\xbe\xdf\xce\xae$\xc8\x95>\xe2\xfd)\xd4\xd4\xfb\x8b\xf4\xa7T\x14-yO\x8b~5\xdbh\x1a\xa5\xf6\x91i\xa4M=\xed\xb4\x86-\xf28X\xcbz\xf1\x92\x7fJ\xee\xbc_\xe28\xfc+\xe1\xab\xadU\xd43F\xa5bV\x1f)\x90\x83\xb47\xa0\'\x03>\xf5\xf3\xdd\xf7\xc5\x9f\x12^<\xb7v\xdan\x95d\xce~y\xe0\xb0\x0c\xc7\xea\xcf\xbb&\x809;\xcdI5\xadGP\xbe\xd6^s}r\xc5\xd6U\xc6\xd4oF\\d\x8cq\xc1\x18\xf7\xe9[\xbe\x1f\xf1\xdf\x8c\xbc;\xe1\xff\x00"\xc6\xea\xe2=#\xcc\xd8&ka"\xc2\xc7\xa8Fa\x80{\xed\xcdeh\x9aN\xab\xe3\x7f\x14Gn\x81\xee..$\xdd<\x98\xe1\x17<\x93\x8e\x00\xaf\xae\xad\xf4\x9b(4x\xb4\xaf\xb2\xc0\xd6i\x10\x88\xc2c\x1b\x08\x03\xa6\xde\x94\x01\xf1\xde\xa9x\xb3\xf8\x92K\xc1{q\xa9\xa9\x95\\\xdc\\)\x12M\xd39\x198\xf4\xc6MzF\xa3\xe0\xdf\x88\x7f\x11\x1e=F\xee8m\xac\xd8\x83o\x04\xd2l\x11\xa7l(\x1e\x95\xc5x\xcfJ\x8fN\xf8\x8d\xa9i\xbatko\x1a^m\x81\x01\xc0L\xe0\x8f\xa0\xe6\xbdkB\xf8\x9f\xaf\xf8b\xe8i\x1e=\xd1\xe7\x8a8@_\xed\x08\xa1<\x0e\x80\xb0Q\xb5\x81\xe9\x95\xfc\x8d\x00z\xfd\x8cs\xc5ao\x1d\xd4\x8b%\xc2D\xab+\xafF`9#\xf1\xaa\xda\xc6\xbb\xa6\xe8\x16mu\xa9\xdd\xc7o\x18\xe9\xb8\xf2~\x83\xbdU\xb6\xf16\x99\xab\xe8\x97W\xfa&\xa1m{\xe5B\xce\x04o\x92\x08\x04\x80\xcb\xd4}\x08\x15\xf2>\xbf\xe2]W\xc4\xda\x83\xdej\x97O3\xb1\xe1I\xf9Pz\x01\xda\x80:\xff\x00\x8a\xbe<\xb7\xf1\xa6\xa7m\x15\x827\xd9-r\x11\x98`\xb1=\xeb\xdb\xfe\x12\xe9si_\x0f\xacb\x9dJ\xbc\xa5\xa6\xc1\xf4n\x9f\xca\xbcW\xe1\xce\x9d\xe06\xb8\x8a\xf7_\xd76\\\xc6r-g\x88\xa2g\xdd\xb9\x07\xf3\xaf\xa4\xf4\x8dWL\xd5\xac\x84\xdaM\xdc\x176\xc8v\x07\x81\xb2\xa0\x8e\xd4\x01\xe4_\x1c|m\x7f\xa6<:\x0e\x9f3A\xe6\xa6\xf9\x9d\x0e\t\x07\xa0\xcdy\xe7\x814i\xb5\xe9\x9eh\xbc_\x0e\x95\xa9#~\xe29\xa6\xda\\\xfbd\xf3\xfa\xd7\xaf|Q\xf8cq\xe3\x0b\x88\xf5\x1d>d[\xb4M\xa5\x1f\x80\xc0t\xaf\'\x83\xc2\x97>\x19\x12\xdbx\xab\xc1\xb77\xb6\xc4\xe4]ZH\xcb$c\xd4\x11\xf2\x91\xec\xc2\x80=s\xc2\xfe<\xd5\xb4\xbf\x11/\x84|l\x91\xa6\xa2@\xfb=\xf4g\xe4\xb8\xf4\xec??\xd2\xb4~&\xf8\xfe\xf7\xc0\xb6\x96\x92Z\xe9\x89r.IS3\xb9\x0b\x19\x1e\xc0s\xf9\x8a\xf0\x9b\x8bO\x0c\xdc\xdd\xe9\xf2i\x1e)\xd4\x81\x8eT\x10ZjV\xa4\xb4?0\xc0\xde\xa7o_A_G\xf8\xc3\xc2\xeb\xe2\x8f\x06\xcf\xa4\xce\xc0\xcf\xe5\x86G\x1d\xa4\x03\xad\x00y\xe7\xc5\x0f\x88~\x7f\x81t\xcbm*b.\xb5\x84\x0c\xc63\x86T\xee?\x13\xc5u\x9f\n\xfc\x1d\'\x86\xfc>\x97W\xd2I.\xa1t\xa1\x9c\xc8\xe4\xec^\xbbFk\xc3\xfe\x19xrmk\xe25\xb5\x8d\xe9g\x8bMfi\x14\x9c\x81\xb0\xf4\x1f\x8d}\\\x00\x00\x000\x05\x00(\xa5\x14R\x8a\x00)i\x05(\xa0\x05\xa5\xa4\xa5\xa0\x05\xa5\xa4\xa5\xa0\x05\xa5\x15Z\xea\xfe\xca\xc17\xde]\xc1n\xbf\xde\x9a@\x83\xf55\xce\xde\xfcK\xf0V\x9f\x9f?\xc4\xbaq#\xa8\x86_4\xff\x00\xe3\x99\xa0\x0e\xb0P+\x83\xd3\xbe0xKX\xd6\xadt\xad2{\xcb\xb9\xae$\x11\xab\xc7j\xe1\x14\x9e\x85\x8b`\x81\xf8Wz(\x00\x15\xcf\\\xff\x00\xc7\xd4\xdf\xef\xb7\xf3\xae\x88W;s\xff\x00\x1fS\x7f\xbe\xdf\xce\xaa$\xc8\x95>\xe2\xfd)\xe2\x98\x9fq~\x94\xfa\x92\x8c\xbf\x10\xe8\x16>\'\xd1\'\xd2\xb5\x15f\xb7\x9b\x04\xecm\xa4\x10r\x08?Q^q\x0f\xec\xff\x00\xa0\x8b\xad\xf3j\x97\xcf\x0es\xe5\xa0U?L\x90\x7f\x95z\xe5(\xa0\x0c\x9d\x03\xc3ZG\x86l\xbe\xcb\xa4\xd9\xa5\xba\x1f\xbc\xc3\x96s\xeaOz\xd7\xa4\x14\xb4\x01\xc0x\xa3\xe1\x16\x85\xe2]fMc\xed7vz\x84\x8c\xae\xef\x13\x06F \x00\tR=\x87B+\xbftY\x11\x91\xd420\xc1V\x19\x04R\xd2\xd0\x07\r\xac\xfc(\xf0\xe6\xa3q\xf6\xdd9f\xd1u\x11\xca\xdc\xe9\xcf\xe5`\xfb\xa8\xe3\xf2\xc1\xf7\xae_T\xd0<]\xa1Z\xb4z\x9e\x85\xa4\xf8\xd7KQ\x80E\xb8\x8e\xedGN\xc0\x9c\xfd7\x1fz\xf6*Z\x00\xf9\x87V\xd0<-#y\x93xg\xc5\xfa\x03\x9eJ\x8b_:\x15\xfc_\r]\xd7\xc3\xaf\x1bx\x0f\xc2\x1a\x13\xe9?\xf0\x90N\xcc\xd3\xb4\xbb\xael\xa4B2\x00\xc7\x00\x8e\xde\xb5\xec\xb5^\xebO\xb2\xbe]\xb7vv\xf7\x03\xd2X\x95\xff\x00\x98\xa0\x0ck_\x1f\xf8B\xeds\x17\x89t\xb1\xed%\xca\xa1\xfc\x98\x8a\xbc<O\xe1\xe6\\\xff\x00ni\x84\x1e\x7f\xe3\xee?\xf1\xac\xdb\xdf\x87>\x0e\xd4Q\x96\x7f\x0ei\xe3wS\x0c"#\xf9\xa6\rT\x1f\t\xfc\x0c\x00\x1f\xf0\x8f[\xf1\xeb$\x9f\xfcU\x00^\x9a\xe7\xc1\x177?h\x9e\xe3@\x92brdi!,O\xb9\xcf5\x0f\x8a5\xcb[\xef\x0e^[h\x9e&\xd2\xadu\x19\x02\x88\xa6k\xb8\xf0\xbf0\xdd\xdf\xfb\xb9\xa8?\xe1S\xf8\x1b\xfe\x85\xdb\x7f\xfb\xf9\'\xff\x00\x15K\xff\x00\n\x9f\xc0\xbf\xf4.\xdb\xff\x00\xdf\xc9?\xf8\xaa\x00\xc2\xf8u\xe1\xff\x00\r\xf8"+\x9b\x8b\x8f\x13i\x97\x9a\x9d\xd9\xfd\xf4\xc2\xe96\x81\xd7\x03\'=y&\xbb\xcf\xf8I\xfc?\xff\x00A\xcd3\xff\x00\x02\xe3\xff\x00\x1a\xc0\xff\x00\x85M\xe0_\xfa\x17m\xff\x00\xef\xe4\x9f\xfcU/\xfc*o\x02\xff\x00\xd0\xbbo\xff\x00\x7f$\xff\x00\xe2\xa8\x03\x7f\xfe\x12\x7f\x0f\xff\x00\xd0wL\xff\x00\xc0\xb8\xff\x00\xc6\x91\xbcU\xe1\xd4R\xcf\xafij\xa3\xa97\x91\x80?Z\xc2\xff\x00\x85M\xe0_\xfa\x17m\xff\x00\xef\xe4\x9f\xfcU#|#\xf0#\xa9S\xe1\xd80}%\x90\x1f\xcc5\x00\\\xbc\xf8\x95\xe0\xbb\x00|\xef\x12\xe9\xcd\x8e\xd0\xcb\xe6\x9f\xfcs5\x87/\xc6\xef\x08y\x86;\x0f\xed-I\xfb-\x9d\x9b\x12\x7f\xef\xad\xb5\xd2\xd8x\x0f\xc2zj\xa8\xb5\xf0\xe6\x98\xa5F\x03\xb5\xba\xbb\x7f\xdfL\t\xfdk~\x18b\x821\x1c1\xa4h:*(\x00~\x02\x80<\xe3\xfe\x16o\x88/\x7f\xe4\x11\xf0\xe7\\\x98\x1f\xba\xf7\x7f\xe8\xe0\xfe$\x11\xfa\xd2\xff\x00k|\\\xd48\xb7\xf0\xe6\x87\xa5\xa9\xefwre#\xfe\xf8o\xe9^\x95J(\x03\xcd?\xe1\x19\xf8\xa7\xa8q}\xe3}>\xc1\x0fU\xb1\xb1\x0f\x8f\xa1`\xa7\xf5\xa5\xff\x00\x85Kw{\xff\x00!\xaf\x1ex\x92\xf4\x1e\xa9\x15\xc7\x94\x87\xfe\x03\xf3\n\xf4\xa1J(\x03\xcfm>\tx\x1a\xdd\xf7\xcf\xa7O{\'R\xf77R\x12~\xbbH\x06\xba;\x1f\x01\xf8KN\xc1\xb5\xf0\xde\x96\x8c:9\xb6Va\xff\x00\x02 \x9a\xe8)h\x01\xb1C\x15\xbcb8bH\xd0tTP\x00\xfc\x05IIK@\x0b\\\xed\xcf\xfc}M\xfe\xfb\x7f:\xe8\xab\x9d\xb9\xff\x00\x8f\xa9\xbf\xdfo\xe7U\x12dG\xb9\xbf\xbc\x7f:]\xed\xfd\xe3\xf9\xd1E0\r\xef\xfd\xe6\xfc\xe8\xde\xff\x00\xdeo\xce\x8a(\x00\xf3\x1f\xfb\xed\xf9\xd1\xe6?\xf7\xdb\xf3\xa2\x8a\x00<\xc7\xfe\xfb~ty\x8f\xfd\xf6\xfc\xe8\xa2\x80\x0f2O\xef\xb7\xe7K\xe6\xc9\xfd\xf6\xfc\xe8\xa2\x80\x0f6O\xf9\xe8\xdf\x9d\x1el\x9f\xf3\xd1\xbf:(\xa0\x03\xcd\x93\xfez?\xe7G\x9d\'\xfc\xf4\x7f\xfb\xe8\xd1E\x00\x1et\xbf\xf3\xd1\xff\x00\xef\xa3G\x9d/\xfc\xf4\x7f\xfb\xe8\xd1E\x00\x1et\xbf\xf3\xd1\xff\x00\xef\xa3G\x9d/\xfc\xf5\x7f\xfb\xe8\xd1E\x00/\x9f/\xfc\xf5\x7f\xfb\xe8\xd1\xe7\xcb\xff\x00=_\xfe\xfa4Q@\x07\x9f7\xfc\xf5\x7f\xfb\xe8\xd1\xe7\xcd\xff\x00=_\xfe\xfa4Q@\x07\x9f7\xfc\xf5\x93\xfe\xfa4}\xa2o\xf9\xed\'\xfd\xf4h\xa2\x80\x0f\xb4M\xff\x00=\xa4\xff\x00\xbe\x8d\x1fh\x9b\xfe{I\xff\x00}\x1a(\xa0\x03\xed\x13\xff\x00\xcfi?\xef\xa3K\xf6\x89\xff\x00\xe7\xb4\x9f\xf7\xd1\xa2\x8a\x00>\xd3?\xfc\xf6\x93\xfe\xfa4}\xa6\x7f\xf9\xed\'\xfd\xf6h\xa2\x80\x0f\xb4\xcf\xff\x00=\xe4\xff\x00\xbe\xcdFIbI$\x93\xc9&\x8a)\xa13\xff\xd9'
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: _I already encoded it_ What do you mean?

Comment: I used the base64 decoding from python on the src String